# Pronunciation of "apartheid"

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, south-african-english

How do South Africans pronounce "apartheid"?  Is there a British/U.S. divide on this?  Does it depend on whether your primary language is Afrikaans or not -- or is that irrelevant?

Does the last syllable rhyme with "paid" or "side"?

I checked some dictionaries with "listen" buttons, but that didn't help me figure out what the *authentic* pronunciation is.  One of them specified one version as U.S. and one version as British, but the layout on the page made it confusing to figure out which was which.

I thought the S. African pronunciation was "paid," but then I heard a Trevor Noah interview on Fresh Air and he said "side."  (But maybe he was just adopting the prevalent U.S. pronunciation....)

On Edwin's suggestion, I listened to four versions at [Oxford Learners](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/apartheid):

- UK: side
- US: side
- UK: paid
- US: paid

(Here I'm just notating the vowel sound, not the final consonant, which I don't care about.)

#### Primary question: Why are there two versions, and which one is more authentically South African?

Secondary question 1: What factors, if any, of the language panorama of South Africa might have been involved in the derivation of these two variants?

Secondary question 2: Can I use the term "etymology" for pronunciation, or is it only for meanings?

Comment: This site (https://www.pronounceitright.com/pronunciation/apartheid-4406) has in Afrikaans (a part' aid); Elsewhere the American ending seems rhyme with "side", the British is more like "site".

Comment: @Xanne - Please copy over to an answer.  Very helpful.

Comment: Both of the Afrikaans pronunciations on [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/af/apartheid/#af) sound to me like they rhyme with *side*, but possibly that is in the ear of the listener so you should listen for yourself. The *r* is much more rolled or trilled than I would expect (or be able to produce) in AmE.

Comment: Lol, the OED says it's "apart-hate" w/ final /t/. But I don't think most people observe word-final hardening like this when pronouncing loanwords from languages with this phenomenon; for example, we pronounce "Freud" as "froyd," not "froyt," and "vodka" has /d/. Phonetically, the Afrikaans/Dutch sound of "ei" is in general near both the vowel of English "paid" and English "side," but I don't know which one is conventionally used by South Africans.

Comment: Interestingly, the Wiki article on "[South African English phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_English_phonology)" indicates that [ʌɪ] is a possible realization of either the "price" or the "face" vowel in SA English, depending on the variety spoken.

Comment: Xanne has adopted the correct approach here. A pronunciation apparently only claimed to be correct in Afrikaans (and not necessarily in SAE) is not what ELU requires. And indeed [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/the-pronunciation-of-south-african-english) claims: 'As a result of apartheid, there is no single, reasonably uniform South African English accent.... There were thus many varieties—white English-speaking SAE, white Afrikaans-speaking South African English, black African South African English, Indian South African English, Coloured South African English....'

Comment: The authentic pronunciation of 'Paris' is rarely used by Anglophones when speaking in English, so it is unwise to argue that more acceptable pronunciations must depend on 'authentic' ones.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Except, for some reason, in the phrase "gay Paris".

Comment: There were 5 listed, and things seem to have changed now anyway. 'Apartheid' is now (also) an English word, and English dictionaries advise on pronunciation. Perhaps a SA English dictionary is what you require.

Comment: What on earth does 'How do South Africans pronounce "apartheid"? Is there a British/U.S. divide on this?' mean? If it means  'How do South Africans pronounce "apartheid"? Also, is there a British/U.S. divide on how the word should be pronounced?', the lack of research shown is a reason for closure. I'm now going to assume that this is the case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Please include the research you've done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. If you want a purely SA English answer, I'm not sure why you're mentioning British and US pronunciations, which are in any case clearly given at say [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/apartheid) (in the order BrE, AmE, BrE, AmE).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I had not tried that dictionary, thank you.  (It took me a little bit to figure out that NAmE means North American English.)  I will edit my question.

Comment: /ˡeɪpərθiːd/, obviously.

Comment: Despite @sumelic's comment, I (in England) have never heard "apartheid" pronounced with final /d/; one prevalent pronunciation here is with -/ait/, with some people using -/eit/.

Comment: What about the R?  In Afrikaans would it be rolled?

Comment: I've made a little edit to make the question clearer, and easier to answer.   Feel free to revert it if you disagree with the edit.

Comment: This is a borrowing (in English) from Afrikaans. Also, the English accent in SA is not like the Afrikaaner accent in English in SA. I would say that I have never heard anyone say apart-tight as claimed in that Merriam Webster definition. I have heard (and I actually was involved in the anti-apartheid struggle/fight) both apart-ide and apart-aid and always with a d at the end, used by English speakers who are not from SA. Amandla!

Comment: In Afrikaans: https://forvo.com/languages/af/ I guess that is where MW got its pronunciation for the word. From the source, as it were. But I have never heard that used by non-South African English speakers, I repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I read -about 30 years ago,from an authoritative South African source, that the word is -(was?)- pronounced,"apart-hate". Nasty, hey, but quite fitting considering its disgusting meaning.

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but this doesn't answer the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you'll be able to comment anywhere.  So go give us a good answer somewhere!

Answer (score -1):

Apartheid is an Afrikaans word which literally translates to “Apartness”. It is pronounced in Afrikaans dialect. It is not a “South African English” word and neither is it pronounced in any English dialect. Google how to pronounce it in Afrikaans. It is an authentic Afrikaans word.

Comment: I speak an English dialect, and I understand and pronounce the word "apartheid" in my dialect. Just because the word's origin is in Afrikaans doesn't mean it hasn't been adopted by English, too - and (as often happens when English adopts words), the pronunciation may be different from that of the source language.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apartheid) seems to think it's an English word, and certainly US and UK press use it as if it was (without any italics or other scare-punctuation).

Comment: This is a borrowing (in English) from Afrikaans. Also, the English accent in SA is not like the Afrikaaner accent in English in SA. I would say that I have never heard anyone say *apart-tight* as claimed in that Merriam Webster definition. I have heard (and I actually was involved in the anti-apartheid struggle/fight) both apart-hide and apart-aid and always with a d at the end, used by English speakers who are not from SA. *Amandla!*

Comment: Magda, if you improve your answer a little bit maybe you could get some upvotes. Take a look at the Help section, top right of your screen under the last icon.